# Scheme theoretic fiber vs. Degree of a point of a finite morphism of affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, localization, affine-schemes

Let $f: R\to S$ be a finite morphism of Commutative Noetherian rings, so $S$ is module finite over $R$ via $f$. Let $Q \in \text{Spec}(S)$, and set $P=f^{-1}(Q)$, so we have an induced map $R_P \to S_Q$. Set $\kappa(P):= \dfrac{ R_P}{PR_P}$. The degree of the induced finite morphism of schemes $f^*: \text{Spec}(S) \to \text{Spec}(R)$ of the point $P$ is given by $\dim_{\kappa(P)} \kappa(P) \otimes_{R_P} S_Q$. The scheme theoretic fiber of $P \in \text{Spec}(R)$ is given by $\kappa(P)\otimes_R S$. My question is:

Is it true that $\dim_{\kappa(P)} \kappa(P) \otimes_{R_P} S_Q = \dim_{\kappa(P)}
 \kappa(P)\otimes_R S$ ?

Comment: Is the second $\dim$ in the last equality supposed to be $\dim_{\kappa(P)}?$

Comment: @Daniel: that would seem to be the natural thing to expect, right?

Comment: Sure! I expected this to be the case. I'm just making sure that I understand your question.

Comment: The two are isomorphic. To see this, note that $S_Q = R_P\otimes_R S$ and then use the identity $A\otimes_B (B \otimes_C D)=A\otimes_C D$.

Comment: Let $R=\mathbb{C}[t^2]$, $S=\mathbb{C}[t]$ (and the map is the inclusion). Take $Q=(t-1)$, then $P=(t^2-1)$.  

So $k(P) \otimes_R S=\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2-1)$ has dimension $2$ over $k(P)=\mathbb{C}$. 

But $k(P) \otimes_R S_Q=\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t-1)}/(t^2-1) \cong \mathbb{C}[t]/(t-1)$ has dimension $1$.

Comment: @ParthShimpi this is not true, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. Here is a simple explicit counterexample: let $k$ be a field, let $R=k$, let $S=k\times k$, and let $f:R\to S$ be given by $a\mapsto (a,a)$. Let $Q=k\times 0$, which makes $P=0$. Then $k(P)=k$, $R_P=R=k$, but $S_Q\cong k$ while $S=k^2$, so $\dim_{k(P)} k(P)\otimes_{R_P} S_Q = \dim_k k\otimes_k k = \dim_k k = 1$ while $\dim_{k(P)} k(P) \otimes_R S = \dim_k k\otimes_k k^2 = \dim_k k^2 = 2$.

For a conceptual explanation of what's going on here, the first dimension depends only on the point $Q$ while the second dimension depends on all the points in the fiber. So as soon as you have multiple points in your fiber, you should expect a difference.